# Unmet dependencies when installing OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu 12.10 and I want to install OpenCV.

I am following the tutorial on [this website](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/) and when I try the second step, meaning

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall git cmake libfaac-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev texi2html yasm zlib1g-dev
```

I get the following error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no idea what this means and how I could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The message means you are trying to install `libsdl1.2-dev`, which needs `libpulse-dev`, but it cannot be installed. Maybe apt could not find `libpulse-dev` in any of your package repositories.